# an idea or module te generate structured text in python?

Tags: python, dynamically-generated, formatted-text

Well first am sorry because i didn't know how to ask my question, last time in a security challenge i was trying to send some request with curl, after a few moment where they have a lot test to find out how the challenge is really working , i tried to write some python code for generating my request automatically and win some time

here are some of the request that i used to try :
The basic one

```
curl http://10.20.0.50:80/
```

then i have to specify the path example :

```
curl http://10.20.0.50:80/transfert/solde
curl http://10.20.0.50:80/account/creat
...
```

some time add authorization or cookie ...

```
curl http://10.20.0.50:80/transfert/solde -H "Authorization:Basic bXlhcGk6U3VwZXJTZWNyZXRQYXMkdzByZA=="  -H "cookie: PHPSESSID=23c3jc3spuh27cru38kf9l2au5;"
```

or add some parameters :

```
curl http://10.20.0.50:80/transfert/solde -H "Authorization:Basic bXlhcGk6U3VwZXJTZWNyZXRQYXMkdzByZA=="  -H "cookie: PHPSESSID=23c3jc3spuh27cru38kf9l2au5;" --data-raw '{"id":"521776"}' -v
```

So the thing is i have to test a lot of thing with and without authorization with and without cookie and changing cookie some times and add --data-raw ... i tried to write a script to do this for me but it's ugly :

```
url = "http://10.20.0.50:80/"
auth = ' -H "Authorization:Basic bXlhcGk6U3VwZXJTZWNyZXRQYXMkdzByZA=="'
def generate(path,c=None,h=True,plus = None):
    #c cookie , h if we put authentification
    #plus add more code at the end of the request
    global auth  # authentification
    global url
    if c:
    cook = ' -H "cookie: PHPSESSID={};"'.format(c)
    req = "curl "+url+path 
    if h:#h bool
        req += auth
    if c :
        req += cook
    if plus :
        req += plus
    req+=" -v "
    return req
```

I removed one parameter the --data-row for readability, the idea is that i want to know if there is a better way for doing that ! and not just with this example but in general, if i want to create python code that generate a code source of class where i have to specify the name of class the attributes and type and the  code generate a template ...

I hope that you can help me :D
PS : Sorry for my English if i mad some mistakes

Comment: first of all, can you fix your python's code indentation ?

Comment: i didn't notice that i dint't past it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, a one way to "improve" your code is doing something like this:

```
def generate(command = "", headers = [], raws = [], other = [], v = True):
    if headers:
        command += "".join(" -H " + k for k in h)
    if raws:
        command += "".join(" --data-raw " + k for k in raw)
    if v:
        command += " -v"
    if other:
        command += "".join(" " + k for k in other)
    return command

h = ['"Authorization:Basic bXlhcGk6U3VwZXJTZWNyZXRQYXMkdzByZA=="', '"cookie: PHPSESSID=23c3jc3spuh27cru38kf9l2au5;"']
raw = ["'{\"id\":\"521776\"}'"]
cmd = "curl http://10.20.0.50:80/transfert/solde"

command1 = generate(command=cmd,headers=h,raws= raw)
command2 = generate(command=cmd,headers=h,raws=raw, v=False)
command3 = generate(command=cmd,v = False)

print("command1:",command1)
print("command2:", command2)
print("command3:", command3)
```

Output:

```
command1: curl http://10.20.0.50:80/transfert/solde -H "Authorization:Basic bXlhcGk6U3VwZXJTZWNyZXRQYXMkdzByZA==" -H "cookie: PHPSESSID=23c3jc3spuh27cru38kf9l2au5;" --data-raw '{"id":"521776"}' -v
command2: curl http://10.20.0.50:80/transfert/solde -H "Authorization:Basic bXlhcGk6U3VwZXJTZWNyZXRQYXMkdzByZA==" -H "cookie: PHPSESSID=23c3jc3spuh27cru38kf9l2au5;" --data-raw '{"id":"521776"}'
command3: curl http://10.20.0.50:80/transfert/solde
```

Comment: Thanx it look nicer :D

Comment: i can do what? rate you missed a letter ? xD 
if you meant rate your answer alredy did it 
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."
but it's invisible :p 
thanks a lot i give me more idea to organize my code